# How to return success/failure messages with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using MailChimp's API and I can successfully subscribe an email address by passing an email address to a specific URL. Once the email is submitted, MailChimp echoes a success or failure code.

Example: myurl.com/subscribe.php?email=example@gmail.com

**What I need help with**

My form isn't displaying the success/failure messages that I've based on MailChimps returned codes. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/WarrenBee/c4MWX/

Comment: the fiddle doesn't work because you're making a cross-domain call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I'm guessing on comments, I'll guess on an answer. I went to `http://yoursite.com/subscribe/mcapi_listSubscribe.php?email=joe@joe.com` in my browser. I got this:

`Unable to load listSubscribe()! Code=220 Msg="joe@joe.com" has been banned`

So, you've got a problem in your server-side code. It can't load a function named listSubscribe(). Also, regardless, you're not returning stuff in [JSON format](http://json.org), but your ajax call is expecting such.

Comment: I have no idea why you got banned. A different email address will work though.

Comment: The ban wasn't the point. That was a bogus email address anyway. The point is the response is not in JSON format, and that you've got an error in your code that is referencing an unloadable function.

Comment: Oh, and the "unable to load..." message ins't a problem at all--the PHP code is fine. listSubscribe() only runs if there are no errors. The problem is that the displayed code isn't being returned to my form.

Comment: @WarrenBee, when I go to the URL now with a fresh email I get: `Subscribed - look for the confirmation email!`. That's not a JSON response. The server needs to return JSON at all times, whether there's an error or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I started realizing the unreliable JSON responses and other issues, so I went with an easier approach that turned out better than my initial idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the ajax operation is failing.  You're trying to post to a URL in a different domain, and that particular server is not set up to allow that.

Comment: Yes, but in his actual page it's not likely a cross-domain call. (I'm basing this on his name being WarrenBee, and the domain he's making call to is warrenbaskin.com). I'm just guessing.

Comment: @JonathanM well you're probably right about that, but there's not much we can do with the jsfiddle.

Comment: Yep, this is one of those rare instances where a fiddle just doesn't help.

Comment: How do I set up the server to allow that?

Comment: Well @WarrenBee I think Jonathan M's answer is what you want to look for. If you're making an ajax call to your own domain from your real site, there's no problem. If you want it to work from a jsfiddle you have to set up your server with CORS headers; I'm not exactly sure how to do that but you should be able to google for it.

Comment: Thanks, Pointy--I will try that out. Please look at my last comment to Jonathan M